# using for loop to get mutiple dataframe that fits my filter conditions with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, filter

i have a dataframe called price, with two main columns in my filter: market segment to set as half hour and the period is the variable (P) which i want to put in my loop to run from P = 1 to 48.  The filter conditions are as follows:

```
P1 = price[(price['Market Segment'] == 'HALF HOUR') & (price['Period'] == 1)])
```

So i would have to change P1 and the number 1 at the end everytime until 48 (so if i do it manually i have to do it 48 times

i.e for the second dataframe i want, P =2 ill have to put in:

```
P2 = price[(price['Market Segment'] == 'HALF HOUR') & (price['Period'] == 2)])
```

and id like to have 48 dataframe at the end to show each P1 - P48?

Also i welcome any resources on for loop examples, this is still very tricky for me
many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them into a dictionary with a loop:

```
df_dict = {f'P{i}': price[(price['Market Segment'] =='HALF HOUR') & (price['Period']==2)] 
           for i in range(1,49)
          }
```

and later access with, e.g, `df_dict['P1']`.

Comment: thank you Sir! however if i want to export each P dataframe to csv i.e. df_dict.to_csv('/Users/loopd.csv') i got 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_csv'. ?

Comment: But you want a list/dict of 48 dataframes. If you want to save them as csv, should you save each one sepatately? For example, `for k, v in df_dict.items(): v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv)`.

Comment: thanks, ill do a bit of google on the k,v, f string you put there!